# Encode into an `enumerate` environment (Version 3)

Tags: lists, enumerate

I have two codes for the same display - a question on a multiple-choice test.  The first code in an `enumerate` environment; the second code is a `tabbing` environment.  I want to get the display from the `enumerate` environment that I get from the `tabbing` environment.  Specifically, I want the problem to be numbered "`4.)`" and I want the same inter-line spacing as that of `text` mode separating the first-level and second-level `enumerate` environments.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{% (
  leftmargin=*, label={\textbf{\arabic*.)}}}

\setlist[enumerate,2]{% (
  label={\textbf{\roman*.)}}}


\begin{document}

\begin{center}\Large{\textbf{Review of High School Algebra}}\end{center}\vskip0.3in



\begin{enumerate}[itemsep=\baselineskip]
\item Express the following decimals as fractions.
  \begin{multicols}{4}
    \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=1.5cm, topsep=\baselineskip]
    \item 1
    \item 0.25
    \item 0.025
    \item 0.0025
    \item 0.125
    \item 0.0125
    \item 1.25
    \item 0.0625
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{multicols}
\end{enumerate}


\noindent \textbf{4.) }Express the following decimals as fractions.
\begin{tabbing}
\hspace*{2em} \= \hspace{1.25in}  \= \hspace{1.25in}  \= \hspace{1.25in} \= \hspace{1.25in} \= \kill
\> \textbf{i.) }1       \> \textbf{ii.) }0.25    \> \textbf{iii.) }0.025 \> \textbf{iv.) }0.0025 \\
\> \textbf{v.) }0.125   \> \textbf{vi.) }0.0125     \> \textbf{vii.) }1.25  \> \textbf{viii.) }0.0625
\end{tabbing}



\end{document}
```

Comment: `Tasks` doesn't do what you want?

Comment: @Bernard  It gives me exactly what I want.  I appreciate you answering my questions.  I will read about the `tasks` package.  I am almost sure that I will use it for typesetting tests and solutions to problems from textbooks.  I think that I should be familiar with the `enumerate` environment to get such a simple display.

Comment: Yes, but with the `multicols` environment, you'll never get a horizontal numbering, which is unnatural for the readet. There is also the `shortlst` package which can do more or less the same as  `` tasks`, but has one advantage: in case an item requires more than one column, it is done automatically.

Comment: @Bernard  That is "news" to me.  I will read the manual on the `tasks` package.

Comment: @Bernard   I would still like to get the code for this post.

Comment: Actually, I don't grasp very well what you're asking with  `the same inter-line spacing as that of text mode separating the first-level and second-level enumerate environments.` Do you mean the vertical spacing between the two levels should be a normal interline spacing?

Comment: @Bernard  Yes.  That is the spacing between the text preceding the `tabbing` environment and the choices of the `tabbing` environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution, again with the `tasks` package. The vertical distance between the preceding text and the environment is set by the `before-skip` key, and the distance between rows of a task environment is set with the `after-item-skip` key. In the following code, the first two environments use the same spacing as with a `tabbing` environment, and the last two use the values of a `\medskip` and a `\bigskip` respectively.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath, nccmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\newlength\labelwd
\settowidth\labelwd{\bfseries viii.)}
\usepackage{tasks}
\settasks{counter-format =tsk[r].), label-format=\bfseries, label-offset=1em, label-align=right, label-width
=\labelwd, before-skip =\smallskipamount, after-item-skip=0pt}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{% (
leftmargin=*, itemsep=12pt, label={\textbf{\arabic*.)}}}


\begin{document}

\begin{center}\Large{\textbf{Review of High School Algebra}}\end{center}\vskip0.3in

\begin{enumerate}[itemsep=\baselineskip, topsep=\baselineskip]
  \item Express the following decimals as fractions.
        \begin{tasks}(4)
          \task 1
          \task 0.25
          \task 0.025
          \task 0.0025
          \task 0.125
          \task 0.0125
          \task 1.25
          \task 0.0625
        \end{tasks}
\end{enumerate}
%

\begin{enumerate}[start =9]
  \item The sum of the (interior) angles of which of the following figures is not a multiple of $360^{\circ}$?
        \begin{tasks}(3)
          \task triangle
          \task trapezoid
          \task isosceles trapezoid
          \task hexagon
          \task octogon
        \end{tasks}
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[topsep=\baselineskip, start=16]
  \item Simplify the following expressions. (Except for the first expression, the following expressions are equal to integers.)

        \begin{tasks}[before-skip =\medskipamount, after-item-skip=1.5pt](3)
          \task $\sqrt{0.25}$
          \task $\sqrt{0}$
          \task $\sqrt{36}$
          \task $\sqrt[\uproot{1} \leftroot{-1} 3]{-1}$
          \task $\sqrt[\uproot{1} \leftroot{-1} 3]{-8}$
          \task $\sqrt[\uproot{1} \leftroot{-1} 3]{(18)(12)}$
        \end{tasks}
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[topsep=1.2\baselineskip, start=25]
  \item $a$ and $b$ are positive real numbers, and $a^{2}b = 1000$. Which of the following expressions is an integer?
        \begin{tasks}[before-skip =\bigskipamount, after-item-skip=1.5pt](3)
          \task $\log(a)$
          \task $\log(b)$
          \task $\log(ab)$
          \task $\log\bigl(\sqrt[\uproot{1} \leftroot{-1} 3]{a^{2}b}\bigr)$
          \task $\mfrac{1}{2} \log(a^{2}b)$
        \end{tasks}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly the display that I wanted!

Comment: Please add `start=16` and `start=25` as options to the last two `enumerate` environments.  I will delete this comment.

Comment: I have one modification that I would like to make - a bit more inter-line spacing between the two rows in `16.)` and `25.)`.

Comment: Here you are, Milady! Is that fine now?

Comment: Kind sir, you did not make either of the edits that I requested.  Please add `start=16` and `start=25` as options to the last two enumerate environments, and add a bit more inter-line spacing between the two rows in `16.)` and `25.)`.

Comment: Sorry, I messed up with the e different versions of the files. It's corrected now. Is it like you want?

Comment: The display and code look the same.  The radical symbol occupies a bit more vertical space than letters or numbers, and this makes the two rows of choices in `3.)` look compact.  Similarly, the numerator of the fraction in the last choice in `5.)` is too close to `log(b)` in the second choice.

Comment: The last point has nothing to do with `tasks`. It's a matter of formatting the equations (the spacing is latex default; anyway I would suggest to use medium sized fractions in this case).

Comment: Please have a look at the new version.

Comment: I see that you added `after-item-skip=1.5pt` as an option to `tasks` environment for `3.)` and `5.)`.  Yes, this is what I want.

Comment: I see that you changed the fraction to `\mfrac{1}{2}`.  In what font are the numerator and denominator typeset?  (I will probably keep the code as `\dfrac{1}{2}`.  In the text in other problems, I have fractions typeset in `\displaystyle`, and I would want the fractions in the choices following it to be in the same style.)

Comment: It was to demonstrate the possibility to have some fractions in medium size. It's the usual font (Computer Modern), and its size  about $80 \%$ of `\displaystyle`. If you want all fractions in \display style, use `\dfrac`, that's all.